# Missing default.aspx when creating site-collection from web template - 404

Tags: site-collection, web-template

I have a custom web template that I use to create a new site-collection. I get the success message, but when I continue to site/default.aspx I get a 404 "The page you're looking for doesn't exist.". I can access `/_layouts/settings.aspx` and everything from that. Looking at `Site Contents` and `Pages` I have one item, which is the `PageNotFoundError.aspx`.

What am I missing that somehows hinder the provisioning of a `default.aspx`?

My `ONET.xml` contains the following that I thought would result in a `default.aspx`

```
   <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
      <!-- Publishing -->
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <!--<Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/icp.portal.master"/>-->
        <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayoutTemplate.aspx"/>
        <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/default.aspx"/>
        <Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value=""/>
        <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
        <Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value=""/>
        <Property Key="AlternateCssUrl" Value="" />
        <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
        <Property Key="EnableModerationOnPages" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableModerationOnDocuments" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableModerationOnImages" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableSchedulingOnPages" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableSchedulingOnDocuments" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableSchedulingOnImages" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableApprovalWorkflowOnPages" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableApprovalWorkflowOnDocuments" Value="false" />
        <Property Key="EnableApprovalWorkflowOnImages" Value="false" />
      </Properties>
    </Feature>
```

Comment: Which base template are you using for your custom web template? Can you post the elments.xml contents

Answer (score 3):

In you custom ONET.XML you need to provision default.aspx as well.

```
        <Module Name="Home" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
        <File Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
            <Property Name="Title" Value="$Resources:cmscore,IPPT_HomeWelcomePage_Title;" />
            <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
            <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
            <Property Name="PublishingPageImage" Value="&lt;img alt=&quot;$Resources:cmscore,IPPT_PressReleaseImage_AltText;&quot; border=&quot;1&quot; hspace=&quot;0&quot; src=&quot;~SiteCollection/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif&quot; vspace=&quot;0&quot;&gt;" />
            <Property Name="ReusableHTML" Value="$Resources:cmscore,IPPT_PressReleaseWelcomePage_Description;" />
        </File>
    </Module>
```

And then call that module from your Configuration:

```
        <Modules>
            <Module Name="Home" />
        </Modules>
```

Please see template examples from your 14/15 folder

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates

Comment: The question regards a WebTemplate, this is for Site definitions no?

Comment: Webtemplate is ONET.xml but with only one Configuration section. Otherwise its the same.

Comment: Well AFAIK you should avoid modules and list templates and similar in WebTemplates and use features instead (see for example http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/web-templates-in-sharepoint-2010-what-you-should-know/)